# 1D FFT on second dimension with clFFT

Tags: opencl

I am trying to perform a complex 1D FFT on the outer dimension of a 2D array using the clFFT library.

Using an array that is NxM where M is the inner dimension (contiguous in memory), I want to take the FFT over N. I thought I could accomplish this by setting the stride to M. However, when M is 2, the FFT is as expected for m=0 but is something unknown for m=1. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have for the plan setup:

```
  cl_context context;
  dev->get_gr_opencl_interface()->get_platform().opencl_context(context);

  size_t fft_length_size_t[] = {fft_length}; // N
  err = clfftCreateDefaultPlan(&m_plan_handle, context, CLFFT_1D, fft_length_size_t);
  if(err != CL_SUCCESS)
  {
    std::cout << "clFFT clfftCreateDefaultPlan Failed." << std::endl;
  }


  size_t fft_stride_size_t[] = {fft_stride}; // M

  err = clfftSetPlanPrecision(m_plan_handle, CLFFT_SINGLE);
  err |= clfftSetLayout(m_plan_handle, CLFFT_COMPLEX_INTERLEAVED, CLFFT_COMPLEX_INTERLEAVED);
  err |= clfftSetResultLocation(m_plan_handle, CLFFT_OUTOFPLACE);
  err |= clfftSetPlanBatchSize(m_plan_handle, batch_size); // Currently 1
  err |= clfftSetPlanInStride(m_plan_handle, CLFFT_1D, fft_stride_size_t);
  err |= clfftSetPlanOutStride(m_plan_handle, CLFFT_1D, fft_stride_size_t);

  if(err != CL_SUCCESS)
  {
    std::cout << "clFFT Plan Configuration Failed." << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tingxing dong on the clmath forum for answering:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clmath/hWppfghKvN4

**Summary**

> You do multiple 1Ds with each 1D at a time.  or  You do batched 1D
>   with many 1D simultaneously.
>
> Both of the two cases, you need to carefully offset your input buffer
>   and output buffer to make sure it is pointing to the correct address.

It works properly when I set the stride (clfftSetPlanInStride and clfftSetPlanOutStride), batch size (clfftSetPlanBatchSize) to M, and set distance (clfftSetPlanDistance) to 1.